# R , Looping through a dataframe , creating a new one with additional content

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, tidyverse

Caution, quite new to R - but I really would like to do this in R instead of java.

My csv-file (Swedish redlist for species 2020 ) looks like this:

```
id,svenskt,latin,Organismgrupp,Kategori,Observationer,Landskapstyp,status_abbrev,Rodlistekriterium
249012,,Abia candens,stekel,Art,3,"Jordbrukslandskap (J) - Stor betydelse, Skog (S) - Har betydelse",DD,
249014,,Abia lonicerae,stekel,Art,2,Skog (S) - Stor betydelse,DD,
261452,,Abia nitens,stekel,Art,0,Jordbrukslandskap (J) - Stor betydelse,DD,
```

- The whole csv-file can be download from [SLU](https://artfakta.se/rodlistan) by pressing the button 'skapa csv-fil'.

The interesting columns for me is only the 'id' and the 'status_abbrev' columns.
I would like to use those columns to update my db-table, doing something like this:

```
sql<- paste("update redlist SET status_abbrev='",abbrev,"' ","where id=",id,sep="")
```

reading the csv-file with this command:

```
library(dplyr)
redlist <- read.csv("rodlistade_arter_tampered_2.csv",header=TRUE);
dat <- select(redlist,'id', 'status_abbrev')
```

the output from the 3 first lines would be:

1. `redlist` is a dataframe, contains the csv with header.
2. `dat`is a dataframe , contains a subset of redlist (id and status_abbrev).

---

But which library would be best to iterate through the 'dat' data-frame to be able to create something like this ?
iterating and picking out abbrev and id and **creating the below string** for each row - (in the end I would like to write these strings to  an sql-batch file and update the roughy 5660-records)

```
sql<- paste("update redlist SET status_abbrev='",abbrev,"' ","where id=",id,sep="")
```

so that my resulting string would be like this (then iterating through the whole file) :

```
update redlist SET status_abbrev=DD where id=249012
```

[screenshot](https://archive.org/details/redlist-2020) of redlist and dat -

best,i

Comment: I don't understand your question, but what you have, basically is going to do that ... in R everything is vectors so you don't have to use a loop to do the same operation on every row.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output for the first three rows?

Comment: Are you asking which library to use to update database records? If so, this is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @RonakShah , no, that is not the case - if you read through my question I want to create a string - doing something similiar in java is quite easy

Comment: @Elin , so how can I create this string -> update redlist SET status_abbrev=DD where id=249012  , then repeating this for all the id's in my redlist ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do it for all the rows? Or you want to select specific id values? What you have there will create one query per row.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::mutate()` and `glue::glue()` you can create the strings like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'glue'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     collapse

str <- 'id,svenskt,latin,Organismgrupp,Kategori,Observationer,Landskapstyp,status_abbrev,Rodlistekriterium
249012,,Abia candens,stekel,Art,3,"Jordbrukslandskap (J) - Stor betydelse, Skog (S) - Har betydelse",DD,
249014,,Abia lonicerae,stekel,Art,2,Skog (S) - Stor betydelse,DD,
261452,,Abia nitens,stekel,Art,0,Jordbrukslandskap (J) - Stor betydelse,DD,'

df <- read_csv(str)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(sql_string = glue("update redlist SET status_abbrev='{status_abbrev}' where id={id}"))

df2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>       id svenskt latin Organismgrupp Kategori Observationer Landskapstyp
#>    <dbl> <lgl>   <chr> <chr>         <chr>            <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 249012 NA      Abia… stekel        Art                  3 Jordbruksla…
#> 2 249014 NA      Abia… stekel        Art                  2 Skog (S) - …
#> 3 261452 NA      Abia… stekel        Art                  0 Jordbruksla…
#> # … with 3 more variables: status_abbrev <chr>, Rodlistekriterium <lgl>,
#> #   sql_string <glue>

df2 %>% pull(sql_string)
#> update redlist SET status_abbrev='DD' where id=249012
#> update redlist SET status_abbrev='DD' where id=249014
#> update redlist SET status_abbrev='DD' where id=261452
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is this what you are looking for?

For database integration, have a look at [DBI](https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am after, I guess I will be able to solve the rest by saving line-by-line to a file (for instance . update_redlist.sql ) - I found this free course ( https://learn.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-the-tidyverse ) guess that could be a start.

Comment: I was wondering about condition within the 'glue'-function.

Comment: I was wondering about conditional within the 'glue'-function, add-ing an 'if-else'-statement depending on the result in the{status_abbrev}-field . I am using 5 abbreviations {'EX', 'NT', 'LC','DD','NE'} and my table has 2 additional fields (English and Swedish)  for writing them out ( where EX translates to 'Extinct' & 'Utdöd'  , NT to 'Near threatened' & 'Nära hotad', LC to 'Least concern' & 'Livskraftig', DD to 'Data deficiency' & 'Kunskapsbrist', NE to 'Not evaluated' & 'Ej bedömd'

Comment: Why would you save line by line to a file rather than just doing something like `write.csv`?

Comment: The code within the {} is valid r code, thus something like this works: `glue("{ifelse(x==0, 'x is zero', 'x is not zero'}")`

Comment: @Elin, thank you Elin -> I found this one (write.csv(redlistsub,'update_redlist.sql')